# PowerBi - Create chart using 2 X axis value and 1 Y axis Value

Tags: powerbi

I want to create chart in powerbi. There are 2 X axis value(Date) and one Y axis value(amount). Below is the source data table.[image]

2. Final table should look like below image
   [image]

Output chart:
[image]

Can someone help me out to put together the chart.

Answer (score 0):

From ShiftDate and BilledDate, add columns Shift_Month, Billed_Month for name of the months in Data Table

[image]

Create calculate Table Billed_Table using DAX: Billed_Table = SUMMARIZE(Data, Data[Billed_month], "Sum_Billed", CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Amount])))

[image]

Create calculate Table Shift_Table using DAX:Shift_Table = SUMMARIZE(Data, Data[Shift_Month], "Sum_Shift", CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Amount])))

[image]

Then join Billed_Table and Shift_Table

[image]

Now go to power view and plot column chart using join_table data

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ashok. It works. I appreciate your time. Since, I have to map existing calculated table with other table. product column is the mapping column. Can we add product Column in both calculated table and then do  join?

Comment: If you add product column in calculated tables then monthwise shiftAmount, BilledAmount get changed. They get split by product then by month. You won't get values you showed in result table.